# Magento hangs/gets stuck on on "order processing" - No order created in back end

Tags: checkout, orders, ce-1.9.1.0

Magento 1.9.1, rwd theme, one step checkout, stripe payment processor

For some reason the order gets stuck after customer presses "Place Order" using credit card. There is no order created in the back end.

We process over 100 orders daily without any issue but at least 4-5 times a week I get a phone call from a customer stating that they had issues placing an order.

We initially thought it was a phone number issue, where customer has spaces or dashes in it, once we asked a customer to delete the spaces and the order went through successfully but other times it didn't.

I don't know if that was a coincidence or there is something really wrong here.

Has any one had such an issue or know of a fix?

Comment: This could be basically anything. You will at least have to start with your log files (`var/log/system.log`, `var/log/exception.log` - maybe there is even a own log file for your payment gateway. `var/reports/` and your server log might be helpful as well) and check whether there is any information available in there.

Comment: Are you using default magenot checkout or 3rd party checkout module?

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? we get the same issue from time to time ( every few weeks)